# How to fetch multiple values from JSON array with nested object using JSONPATH?

Tags: json, jsonpath

I need to fetch multiple values from a JSON array with nested objects (example JSON below) using JSONPATH.

```
{
    "store": {
       "name": "ABC Co",
        "book": [
            {
                "category": "reference",
                "author": "Nigel Rees",
                "title": "Sayings of the Century",
                "price": 8.95,
                "edition": {
                       "year": 1990,
                       "published_by": "MacMillan"
                 }
            },
            {
                "category": "fiction",
                "author": "Evelyn Waugh",
                "title": "Sword of Honour",
                "price": 12.99,
                "edition": {
                       "year": 1980,
                       "published_by": "MacMillan"
                 }
            }
        ]
     }
}
```

When I tried, this works good upto parent object level.

```
store.book[0].[title,author]
```

```
["Sayings of the Century", "Nigel Rees"]
```

Now I want to fetch child object values (edition.year) too. Something like this:

```
["Sayings of the Century", "Nigel Rees", 1990]
```

But the below expression is not working:

```
store.book[0].[title,author,edition.year]
```

Can anyone help on this? Thanks.

Comment: Was the answer helpful in some way? Consider voting/accepting.

Answer (score 1):

with [JSONPath-Plus](https://jsonpath-plus.github.io/JSONPath/docs/ts/index.html) you can use the below query

```
store.book[0].[title,author,year]
```

Tested here: https://jsonpath.com/

[image]

Comment: The query shown above also works in Goessner's JS implementation (v8.x).

Answer (score 0):

The feature at play here is called union. While there is no binding standard on how to implement unions in a JsonPath library, most only allow two union two properties.
C. Burgmer compiled an overview of different [JsonPath implementations and their behavior](https://cburgmer.github.io/json-path-comparison/), and there is not even a feature to union more than two (flat) properties listed. So, this is implementation-specific, and most don't support it.

The next best thing I found is union'ing three properties on the same level using Goessner's JsonPath or JsonPath-Plus (both JavaScript):

```
$.store.book[0].[title,author,edition]
```

Which results in

```
[
  "Sayings of the Century",
  "Nigel Rees",
  {
    "year": 1990,
    "published_by": "MacMillan"
  }
]
```

You can try it online [here](https://jsonpath.com/) or [here (Goessner tab)](https://jsonpath.com/).

Comment: with JSONPath-Plus you can directly use the child property and it does bring the desired result

Comment: @AkshayG Unfortunately, your proposed solution is not correct. Your query gets the wrong year (`1980`) from the second book item instead of `1990` of `book[0]`.

Comment: It gets 1990. Are you sure it behaved differently when you tried?

Comment: @AkshayG After retesting it now also yields the correct result for me. I wonder if the result is not stable when queried this way. Anyway. Upvoted.